# SQLite SELECT query across multiple columns with duplicate grouped rows

Tags: python, sql, arrays, sqlite

I'm not entirely sure how I can put together a single SQLite query to achieve the following. I can get bits and pieces to work, but can't seem to meld it all into one single one.

I have a table that looks like this (the real data set is several GB):

```
| ID | ColumnA | ColumnB | ColumnC | ColumnD |
| 1  |    21   |    34   |   10    | 0.12654 |
| 2  |    21   |    34   |   20    | 0.25478 |
| 3  |    21   |    46   |   10    | 0.43564 |
| 4  |    21   |    46   |   20    | 1.02487 |
| 5  |    34   |    21   |   10    | 0.01476 |
| 6  |    34   |    21   |   20    | 0.87265 |
| 7  |    34   |    46   |   10    | 0.46478 |
| 8  |    34   |    46   |   20    | 0.13665 |
| 9  |    46   |    21   |   10    | 0.04189 |
| 10 |    46   |    21   |   20    | 0.91754 |
| 11 |    46   |    34   |   10    | 0.73688 |
| 12 |    46   |    34   |   20    | 0.24299 |
```

This data is generated by a nested do-loop for some simulations I'm carrying out.

From this table, I essentially need to extract a table that looks like the following, so that I can plot a color/heatmap.

```
| ID | ColumnA | ColumnB | ColumnC | ColumnD |
| 1  |    21   |    34   |   10    | 0.12654 |
| 3  |    21   |    46   |   10    | 0.43564 |
| 5  |    34   |    21   |   10    | 0.01476 |
| 8  |    34   |    46   |   20    | 0.13665 |
| 9  |    46   |    21   |   10    | 0.04189 |
| 12 |    46   |    34   |   20    | 0.24299 |
```

So this will enable me to make a colormap based on ColumnD values using a 2D-array (the diagonal should be set to zero, as the values of ColumnA and ColumnB are never equal for a given row; hence data for the diagonal is not present in the database):

```
   | 21 | 34 | 46
------------------
21 | 0  |    |
------------------
34 |    | 0  |
------------------
46 |    |    | 0
```

My question is basically how I can set up a single query to aggregate all the data that goes into the 2D array to generate the colormap.

It's important to note that ColumnA and ColumnB are basically populated by the same set of integers. I can obtain the unique list of integer values using DISTINCT. I've found some SO threads about selecting DISTINCT across multiple columns, however none of the examples show how to use an aggregator to pick values in the other columns. In this case, I want to use min() to select the lowest value in ColumnD, for each pair of ids in ColumnA and ColumnB. Selecting DISTINCT on a single column doesn't work, because it's the coordinate pair (ColumnA,ColumnB) that's distinct.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It isn't clear how you go from the original table to the extracted table. The two look exactly the same. What are your criteria?

Comment: Sorry, maybe that got lost in the text. The criteria is selecting for each (ColumnA,ColumnB) pair, the minimum value for ColumnD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, it looks like you want the minimum value of `ColumnD` for pairs of `ColumnA` and `ColumnB`.  If you don't care about the `id` or `ColumnC`, a simple `group by` is sufficient:

```
select ColumnA, ColumnB, min(ColumnD)
from table t
group by ColumnA, ColumnB;
```

If you do need all the values in the row, you can `join` back to get them:

```
select t.*
from table t join
     (select ColumnA, ColumnB, min(ColumnD) as ColumnD
      from table t
      group by ColumnA, ColumnB
     ) tt
     on t.ColumnA = tt.ColumnA and t.ColumnB = tt.ColumnB and
        t.ColumnD = tt.ColumnD;
```

This assumes that `ColumnD` is never duplicated for values in `ColumnA` and `ColumnB`.

Comment: Excellent! I had seen the `group by` feature. Seems to work as desired. `ColumnD` should not be duplicated since I store it till floating-point precision and it's unlikely that two simulations will result in exactly the same value. On the off chance that there is a clash, will `min` throw an error?

Comment: @kartikkumar . . . Not at all.  You would get all rows with the minimum value in the output.

Comment: Great! That works, I guess I could use DISTINCT to ensure only one row gets picked.

Comment: @Karikkumar . . . You can try it, but that has a fair amount of overhead on large result sets.  So, if the performance of `DISTINCT` is a problem, you might want to ask another question about performance.

Comment: the bigger issue I'm facing is unstacking the table fetched from the database into a 2D mesh, so that I can plot a heatmap. Trying to get it to work with Pandas but it's messing up the order of the ColA and ColB elements.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a GROUP BY clause to group the fields that you want to collate rows for and perform aggregate calculations on:

```
SELECT ColumnA, ColumnB, Min(ColumnC), Min(ColumnD)
FROM Table1
GROUP BY ColumnA, ColumnB
```

Comment: This doesn't work for the last example in the desired results.

Comment: That's true. Apologies, I hadn't looked in detail at the desired results.