# Retrieving and plotting ordered, 2D heatmap data from a SQLite database

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, matplotlib, pandas

I've been trying to grapple with this most of this week and I figured I'm probably best placed to ask for some assistance here. I have 2D array data stored in a SQLite database, which I would like to fetch and visualize. There are a number of constraints on how I need to fetch and plot the data though that I'm not sure how to handle.

So, I have a database with a table containing something like the following:

```
| ID | SourceID | TargetID | Parameter | Values  |
| 1  |    21    |    34    | 23.46513  | 0.12654 |
| 2  |    21    |    34    | 23.46513  | 0.25478 |
| 3  |    21    |    46    | 23.46513  | 0.43564 |
| 4  |    21    |    46    | 23.46513  | 1.02487 |
| 5  |    34    |    21    | 14.56319  | 0.01476 |
| 6  |    34    |    21    | 14.56319  | 0.87265 |
| 7  |    34    |    46    | 14.56319  | 0.46478 |
| 8  |    34    |    46    | 14.56319  | 0.13665 |
| 9  |    46    |    21    | 7.99581   | 0.04189 |
| 10 |    46    |    21    | 7.99581   | 0.91754 |
| 11 |    46    |    34    | 7.99581   | 0.73688 |
| 12 |    46    |    34    | 7.99581   | 0.24299 |
```

Some features of this data set to note:

- `ID` is the key and is unique
- The `SourceID` and `TargetID` values are from the same set. In this case, they both contain {21, 34, 46}. The `SourceID` column constitutes the x-axis data for the heatmap and the `TargetID` column constitutes the y-axis data.
- The `Values` column contains the data that has to be plotted in the heatmap.
- The `Parameter` column is the column I need to use to sort the data, since I need to create an ordered heatmap. In this case, `Parameter` is based on values associated with each `SourceID` and `TargetID`.

The following table shows the association of each `SourceId`/`TargetId` with a `Parameter` value:

```
| SourceID/TargetID | Parameter |
|       46          | 7.99581   |
|       34          | 14.56319  |
|       21          | 23.46513  |
```

Based on another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28279996/sqlite-select-query-across-multiple-columns-with-duplicate-grouped-rows.) that I posed, I know that I can reduce this table to unique combinations of (`SourceId`, `TargetId`) based on the minimum of `Values` using a SQL query like:

```
SELECT SourceID, TargetID, min(Values)
  FROM dataset
  GROUP BY SourceID, TargetID;
```

This yields the following reduced table:

```
| ID | SourceID | TargetID | SourceSort | Values  |
| 1  |    21    |    34    |  23.46513  | 0.12654 |
| 3  |    21    |    46    |  23.46513  | 0.43564 |
| 5  |    34    |    21    |  14.56319  | 0.01476 |
| 8  |    34    |    46    |  14.56319  | 0.13665 |
| 9  |    46    |    21    |  7.99581   | 0.04189 |
| 12 |    46    |    34    |  7.99581   | 0.24299 |
```

The bit I'm struggling with is that I now need to order this table based on the values in `Parameter`. If I add `ORDER BY Parameter` to the SQL query, it successfully orders the `SourceID` column, but the `TargetID` column doesn't sort according to this for rows that have the same `SourceID`. In a nutshell, I want to obtain the following table:

```
| ID | SourceID | TargetID | Values  |
| 12 |    46    |    34    | 0.24299 |
| 9  |    46    |    21    | 0.04189 |    
| 8  |    34    |    46    | 0.13665 |        
| 5  |    34    |    21    | 0.01476 |
| 3  |    21    |    46    | 0.43564 |
| 1  |    21    |    34    | 0.12654 |
```

An example of what's underlying this sorting: the table is firstly sorted based on `SourceID` ordering using `Parameter` values. Subsequently, `TargetID` is sorted based on `Parameter` ordering, for rows where the `SourceID` values are equal, e.g., Row 1 (`ID=8`) is sorted before Row 2 (`ID=5`) because `TargetID = 46` should be sorted before `TargetID = 21` based on the associated `Parameter` values.

Finally, with this table, I need to construct a heatmap:

```
(TargetID ordered by `Parameter ASC`)
 ^
 |
 | 
----------------------------------
21 | 0.04189 | 0.01476 |    0    |
----------------------------------
34 | 0.24299 |    0    | 0.12654 |
----------------------------------
46 |    0    | 0.13665 | 0.43564 |
----------------------------------
   |    46   |    34   |    21  --> (SourceID ordered by `Parameter ASC`)
```

To achieve this, I'm using the `Python` `Pandas` library, and executing the SQL query using the `read_sql()` function. I've discovered that I can use `matplotlib`'s `pcolor()` function to plot the heatmap. I'd like to plot the values in the 2D array using a colormap, and I'd like the ordering of the data set to be exactly like above. Finally, I'd then like to plot the `SourceID` and `TargetID` values as tick labels.

This seems like something that should be doable, but so far, I've only been able to generate the heatmap without the ordering according to `Parameter`. I don't know if I'm best placed to solve the ordering bit directly in the SQL statement, or if I should just fetch the data and then sort the `DataFrame` that is returned by `read_sql()`.

In any case, I'd greatly appreciate input! If anything is unclear, please let me know and I'll try to clarify.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way (I see) to convert the sqlite table into the format Matplotlib's `pcolor` requires to draw a heat map is to use the Pandas DataFrame's `pivot` method. Since this `pivot` will reorder the column and rows, there is no need to fuss over the order generated by the SQL query. Instead, it is easier to fix the order in Pandas:

```
import io
import sqlite3
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

text = '''\
| ID | SourceID | TargetID | Parameter | Values  |
| 1  |    21    |    34    | 23.46513  | 0.12654 |
| 2  |    21    |    34    | 23.46513  | 0.25478 |
| 3  |    21    |    46    | 23.46513  | 0.43564 |
| 4  |    21    |    46    | 23.46513  | 1.02487 |
| 5  |    34    |    21    | 14.56319  | 0.01476 |
| 6  |    34    |    21    | 14.56319  | 0.87265 |
| 7  |    34    |    46    | 14.56319  | 0.46478 |
| 8  |    34    |    46    | 14.56319  | 0.13665 |
| 9  |    46    |    21    | 7.99581   | 0.04189 |
| 10 |    46    |    21    | 7.99581   | 0.91754 |
| 11 |    46    |    34    | 7.99581   | 0.73688 |
| 12 |    46    |    34    | 7.99581   | 0.24299 |'''

def make_table(filename):
    # make sqlite table
    with sqlite3.connect(filename) as con:
        df = pd.read_table(io.BytesIO(text), sep=r'\s*[|]\s*').iloc[:, 1:-1]
        df.to_sql('dataset', con=con, if_exists='replace')

filename = '/tmp/data.sqlite'
make_table(filename)

with sqlite3.connect(filename) as con:
    sql = '''
        SELECT SourceID, TargetID, min(`Values`) as min_value
          FROM dataset 
          GROUP BY SourceID, TargetID
    '''
    df = pd.read_sql(sql, con)
    table = df.pivot(index='SourceID', columns='TargetID', values='min_value')

    sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT SourceID FROM dataset ORDER BY Parameter ASC'
    order = pd.read_sql(sql, con)['SourceID']
    table = table.reindex(index=order, columns=order)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.pcolor(table.values, cmap=plt.get_cmap('jet'), 
              vmin=df['min_value'].min(), vmax=df['min_value'].max())
    ax.set_xticks(np.arange(table.shape[1] + 1)+0.5, minor=False)
    ax.set_xticklabels(table.columns, minor=False)
    ax.set_yticks(np.arange(table.shape[0] + 1)+0.5, minor=False)
    ax.set_yticklabels(table.index, minor=False)
    ax.set_xlim(0, table.shape[1])
    ax.set_ylim(0, table.shape[0])
    plt.show()
```

yields

[image]

Comment: Excellent! I had tried something similar but I think I used index() instead of reindex() and it didn't work. Your example works like a peach on my real data! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your sqlite table is not well-formed because the Parameter values only reflect
the Parameter's association with the SourceID, but not the TargetID.

It would be better to have two tables:

**id_param**:

```
id  parameter
21   23.46513
34   14.56319
46    7.99581
```

**dataset** -- note there is no Parameter column here:

```
ID  SourceID  TargetID   Values
 1        21        34  0.12654
 2        21        34  0.25478
 3        21        46  0.43564
 4        21        46  1.02487
 5        34        21  0.01476
 6        34        21  0.87265
 7        34        46  0.46478
 8        34        46  0.13665
 9        46        21  0.04189
10        46        21  0.91754
11        46        34  0.73688
12        46        34  0.24299
```

then you can use JOINs to form the desired associations between both
SourceID/Parameter and TargetID/Parameter:

```
    SELECT d.SourceID, d.TargetID, min(d.`Values`) as min_value
      FROM dataset d
      JOIN id_param as ip1
      ON d.SourceID = ip1.id
      JOIN id_param as ip2
      ON d.TargetID = ip2.id
      GROUP BY SourceID, TargetID
      ORDER BY ip1.parameter ASC, ip2.parameter ASC
```

For example,

```
import io
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

text = '''\
| ID | SourceID | TargetID | Parameter | Values  |
| 1  |    21    |    34    | 23.46513  | 0.12654 |
| 2  |    21    |    34    | 23.46513  | 0.25478 |
| 3  |    21    |    46    | 23.46513  | 0.43564 |
| 4  |    21    |    46    | 23.46513  | 1.02487 |
| 5  |    34    |    21    | 14.56319  | 0.01476 |
| 6  |    34    |    21    | 14.56319  | 0.87265 |
| 7  |    34    |    46    | 14.56319  | 0.46478 |
| 8  |    34    |    46    | 14.56319  | 0.13665 |
| 9  |    46    |    21    | 7.99581   | 0.04189 |
| 10 |    46    |    21    | 7.99581   | 0.91754 |
| 11 |    46    |    34    | 7.99581   | 0.73688 |
| 12 |    46    |    34    | 7.99581   | 0.24299 |'''

def make_table(filename):
    # make sqlite table
    with sqlite3.connect(filename) as con:
        df = pd.read_table(io.BytesIO(text), sep=r'\s*[|]\s*').iloc[:, 1:-1]
        df.to_sql('dataset', con=con, if_exists='replace')


filename = '/tmp/data.sqlite'
make_table(filename)

with sqlite3.connect(filename) as con:
    con.execute('DROP TABLE id_param')

    sql = '''CREATE TABLE id_param 
             (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, parameter INTEGER)'''
    con.execute(sql)

    sql = '''INSERT INTO id_param
             SELECT SourceID, Parameter
             FROM dataset
             GROUP BY SourceID'''
    con.execute(sql)

    sql = '''
        SELECT d.SourceID, d.TargetID, min(d.`Values`) as min_value
          FROM dataset d
          JOIN id_param as ip1
          ON d.SourceID = ip1.id
          JOIN id_param as ip2
          ON d.TargetID = ip2.id
          GROUP BY SourceID, TargetID
          ORDER BY ip1.parameter ASC, ip2.parameter ASC
    '''
    df = pd.read_sql(sql, con)
    print(df)
```

yields

```
   SourceID  TargetID  min_value
0        46        34    0.24299
1        46        21    0.04189
2        34        46    0.13665
3        34        21    0.01476
4        21        46    0.43564
5        21        34    0.12654
```

Comment: I just tried this and it's not exactly what I'm trying to achieve. It just so happens that in the example above, the final table is sorted with `TargetID` descending, but what I need is for the query to break tries by sorting `TargetID` by `Parameter ASC`

Comment: In that case I think you must use JOINs to associate the parameter values with SourceID and TargetID independently. I've edited the post to show what I mean.

Comment: Yea thanks, I can't see that that would be the right way to do this, but I don't have the option of reforming the SQL db at the moment, so I accepted your other answer instead. This SQL-based solution will definitely come in handy for future reference.